# Adding a footer web part zone to dispform.aspx

Tags: 2013, display-form, web-part-zone

I was hoping one of you could help me with an issue I am having.  I have to add a footer web part zone to dispform.aspx on a list in SharePoint 2013.  Our SharePoint 2013 platform is heavily customized, and currently dispform.aspx has 2 columns, a left web part zone and a right web part zone.  My attempts in adding this footer (via SharePoint Designer) have resulted in breaking the form forcing me to reset it to the site definition.  I have tried googling this question, but it doesn't seem a popular topic.

Comment: To add a new web part zone you will have to use SharePoint designer.  Please check that you have added the web part zone code correctly (copy from above and make sure to change IDs etc),  there is no reason for it to break the form,  what error do you get.

Comment: Make sure you have distinct property values for each webpart zone.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you wont do a lot of custom things :
1. You could edit the dispform page by getting its url
2. Add a content editor webpart below with your custom html

details on 
http://lindachapman.blogspot.sg/2010/09/how-to-add-web-part-to-dispformaspx.html

Let me know how you figured out

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest completely changing the Dispform.aspx for the specific list (or content type altogether) with a custom page. You can add your extra WebPartZone in there.

Reference: http://sharepointbuzzer.com/2013/10/19/replace-dispform-aspx-for-list-or-content-type/

http://sp2013.blogspot.com.ar/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-list-custom-form.html